# jquery function to CREATE A TABLE depending of SELECTED VALUE by a SECOND jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is my html code part:

```
   <div class="col-lg-1 ">
              <select class="form-control" name="device_nbre" id="device_nbre">
                <option value="0" active>0</option>
                <option value="1" >1</option>
                <option value="2" >2</option>
                <option value="3" >3</option>
                <option value="4" >4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <div class="device_list" name="device_list" id="device_list"></div>
            </div>
```

the "device_list" is generated by this function:

```
    $("#device_nbre").change(function(e){
    var nbredevice=$(this).val();
    var dataString ='nbredevice='+ nbredevice;

                $.ajax( {
                    url:'../php/device_nbre.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(result){

                    $(".device_list").html(result);
                    }
                    })  
                });
```

the result inside the "device_list" is:
//Nota: "device_1" is generated by a loop inside the device_nbre.php file, it can be device_2,device_3,.....,device_n.

```
<table id="device_table">
            <thead>
               <tr>
               <th class="col-lg-2">id</th>
               <th class="col-lg-3">model</th>

               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td class="col-lg-3" >1</td>
                <td class="col-lg-3" >
                  <div class="device">
                   <select class="form-control" id="device_1" name="device_1" > //select the device1
                       <option value="-1" active >Select...</option>
                       <option value="0">The First_device_ref</option>
                       <option value="1">The Second_device_ref</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
               </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="table_device" name="table_device_1" id="table_device_1"></div>   //will be generated by selecting option see before
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col-lg-3" >2</td>
                <td class="col-lg-3" >
                  <div class="device">
                   <select class="form-control" id="device_2" name="device_2" > //select the device2
                       <option value="-1" active >Select...</option>
                       <option value="0">The First_device_ref</option>
                       <option value="1">The Second_device_ref</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
               </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="table_device" name="table_device_2" id="table_device_2"></div>   //will be generated by selecting option see before
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
      <table>
```

I would like to create the "div class="table_device_Id"" for each "device_Id" selected by a new jquery $POST function but i am not able to find the solution to generate it by onChange() jquery function

Thanks for you help!!
Ludo

Comment: I do not really understand your question. What do you mean by ".. like to create the "" for each..."?

Comment: Sorry Grimbode, mistake on the comment  do you think you can help me?

Comment: Yeah I'll try. So far I understand what you're trying to do till you say "selected by a new jquery $POST function but i am not able to find the solution to generate it by onChange() jquery function". Could you be a little more precise on what you mean by that?

Comment: Hi Grimbode.  The first part of the html code is generated by the jquery function => $("#device_nbre").change(function(e).  In this code, i need select an option, and onChange, i post the value by a new function. The result will be show in a new div

Comment: Yes, this part I understood. Howerver, you want a  new ajax event for the "table_device_id" div. I see that these divs are generated after the "device_nbre" select change. My next question is: I see you have generated new selects from the first ajax. Are those selects linked directly to the "table_device_id"? Is this what you're having problems with?

Comment: yes, the "table_device_id" depend of the new selects value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Supposing that I understood the problem:(and will update till I understand it fully)*

You currently have an `on change` event for your first select which will make an ajax request. The result will be directly added to your `device list div`. If I understand correctly all the above works.

Your problem seems to be that you want to create a second ajax request, because within your result (from your first ajax response) you create a list of devices that each have a select and a new container for the second ajax response results?

If this is the problem then the solution is the following:

1. You need to add an on change event directly in your first ajax's success function. You should add a specific class to your select. Seeing you don't I'll use the `class="device"` your parent uses.
2. We'll be accessing a class so any of the select's being changed will trigger the event. Once the event is triggered we know which select we are at with `$(this)`
3. Next we just need to find the **table_device_id** that is supposed to go with your **select** which is easy since your select has an *id with a number*. We'll need that number to recreate your "table_device_id" id name.

   4. Call your request and fill in the information in your "table_device_id"

JS:

```
$.ajax( {
  url:'../php/device_nbre.php',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: dataString,
  success: function(result){

     $(".device_list").html(result);
     $(".device select").on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        // Here we get that special number from the current id and make a new id.. the one that responds to table_device_id
        var table_device_id_name = '#table_device_' + $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
        secondAjax(val, table_device_id_name);
     });
   }
  })  
});

function secondAjax(val, id){
  $.ajax({
    // I'll let you fill this part out

   success: function(result){
     $(id).html(result);
   }
  });
}
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted or not.

Comment: i added the part of the second Ajax:    url:'../php/device_nbre.php',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: "device="+val,
  Issue is table_device_id_name become table_device_0 if selected option value is 0 and table_device_1 if the selected option value is 1  but if i choose the same device, i will have 2 table with the same name...  what do u think about?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I'll re-explain what table_device_id_name is coming from. You'll notice in your device selects, that you gave them an id.. for example: "device_1". I take the "1" from the string to build "table_device_1". I do not use the selected option's value to build "table_device_n"... unless that is what you wanted?

Comment: table_device_id come from the first ajax  id is a variable depending of the number value selected on the first select

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project.